# Fourier series, Fourier transform for $f(t)=\cos{t}$ - amplitude spectrum vs. frequency spectrum vs. power density spectrum

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(t)=\cos{t}$ and $t \in \left[-\pi, \pi\right]$.

**The associate Fourier series** is computed using the following formula:

$$a_{0}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}{\cos(t)dt}=0$$

$$a_{n>1}=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}{\cos(t)\cos(nt)}dt=-\frac{2n\sin(\pi n)}{n^2-1}=0$$

$$b_{n}=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}{\cos(t)\sin(nt)}dt=0$$
**The associate Fourier transform** is computed using the following formula:
$$F(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \cdot \int^{\pi}_{-\pi}{f(t) \cdot e^{izt}dt}. $$
After computing, I obtained: $$F(z)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} \cdot \frac{z \cdot \sin(z \pi)}{1-z^{2}}. $$

My **questions** are:

1. How can I obtain the **Power Density Spectrum** from *Fourier Transform*?
2. Which are the differences between amplitude spectrum, frequency spectrum and power density spectrum?
3. Can you recommend me some information regarding spectrum analysis for Fourier series and Fourier transform?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, the associated Fourier series is $\displaystyle S(f)(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n e^{i n t}$ where $c_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t) e^{-int} dt$. Of course $c_n = \frac{F(n)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Comment: And the spectrum of a periodic function is the sequence of coefficients $c_n$, the spectrum of a non-periodic function is its Fourier transform $F(\omega)$ . Often, you look only at the amplitude of this spectrum so $|c_n|,|F(\omega)|$ or the squared amplitude (the power) $|c_n|^2,|F(\omega)|^2$. That's all

Comment: thanks for you answer. Your sentence "Often, you look only at the amplitude of this spectrum so $\left|c_n\right|$, $\left|F(\omega)\right|$ or the squared amplitude (the power) $\left|c_n\right|^{2}$, $\left|F(\omega)\right|^{2}$" is not very clear... squared amplitude is for the power and the normal one is for amplitude spectrum?

Comment: so it was very clear indeed